# Pandas time series: groupby and sum from noon to noon

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My pandas dataframe is structured like this (with 'date' as index):

```
           starttime  duration_seconds
date                                  
2012-12-24  11:52:00             31800
2012-12-23   0:28:00             35940
2012-12-22   2:00:00             26820
2012-12-21   1:57:00             23520
2012-12-20   1:32:00             23100
2012-12-19   0:50:00             25080
2012-12-18   1:17:00             24780
2012-12-17   0:38:00             25440
2012-12-15  10:38:00             32760
2012-12-14   0:35:00             23160
2012-12-12  22:54:00              3960
2012-12-12   0:21:00             24060
2012-12-10  23:45:00               900
2012-12-11  11:00:00             24840
2012-12-10   0:27:00             25980
2012-12-09  19:29:00              4320
2012-12-09   3:00:00             29880
2012-12-08   2:07:00             34380
```

I use the following to groupby date and sum the total seconds each day:

```
df_sum = df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()
```

What I'd like to do is sum duration_seconds from noon on one day to noon on the following day. Is there an elegant (pandas) way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.TimeGrouper` is a custom groupby class for time-interval grouping of NDFrames with a `DatetimeIndex`, `TimedeltaIndex` or `PeriodIndex`. (If your dataframe index is using date-strings, you'll need to convert it to a DatetimeIndex first by using `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)`.)

`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('24H')).sum()` groups `df` using 24-hour intervals starting at time `00:00:00`.

`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('24H'), base=12).sum()` groups `df` using 24-hour intervals starting at time `12:00:00`:

```
In [90]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('24H', base=12)).sum()
Out[90]: 
                     duration_seconds
2012-12-07 12:00:00           34380.0
2012-12-08 12:00:00           34200.0
2012-12-09 12:00:00           26880.0
2012-12-10 12:00:00           24840.0
2012-12-11 12:00:00           28020.0
2012-12-12 12:00:00               NaN
2012-12-13 12:00:00           23160.0
2012-12-14 12:00:00           32760.0
2012-12-15 12:00:00               NaN
2012-12-16 12:00:00           25440.0
2012-12-17 12:00:00           24780.0
2012-12-18 12:00:00           25080.0
2012-12-19 12:00:00           23100.0
2012-12-20 12:00:00           23520.0
2012-12-21 12:00:00           26820.0
2012-12-22 12:00:00           35940.0
2012-12-23 12:00:00           31800.0
```

---

Documentation on `pd.TimeGrouper` is a little sparse. It is a subclas of [`pd.Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) and thus many of its parameters have the same meaning as those documented for `pd.Grouper`. You can find more examples of `pd.TimeGrouper` usage in the [Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#resampling). I found the `base` parameter by inspecting [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/resample.py#L982). The `base` parameter in `pd.TimeGrouper` has the same meaning as the `base` parameter in [`pd.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and that is not surprising since `pd.resample` is [implemented using `pd.TimeGrouper`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/resample.py#L941).

In fact, come to think of it, another way to compute the desired result is

```
df.resample('24H', base=12).sum()
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you !